# MS-ACCESS: displaying the results of a query in a message box

Tags: ms-access

how do i feed the result of a query into a msgbox in access?

Comment: Multiple rows are not appropriate for a MsgBox() in Access. You need a datasheet or continuous form that you can pop up to display the results where you've contemplated using a MsgBox().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to use a recordset.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs=CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("NameOfQuery_Table_Or_SQLString")

If Not rs.EOF Then
   MsgBox "Hi, the first record, first field is " & rs.Fields(0)
End if
```

You could also use an ADO recordset if you wish to return all the records to a string.

It might be easier to use [`DLookUp`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786), it all depends on what you want returned and from where.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but to set the text displayed in a message box you can call:

```
MsgBox strYourTextHere
```

[Here's the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012288861033.aspx) for the MsgBox function for Access 2007.

Comment: i want something like msgbox MyQuery

Comment: What does MyQuery return?  If it's a string it should work (within the limitations imposed by the MsgBox function's 'prompt' parameter - see the documentation in my link).

Comment: SELECT users.id, users.first, users.last, chavrusas.luser_type AS user_type, chavrusas.id, users.title, users.city, users.state, users.home_phone, users.email  FROM Users INNER JOIN chavrusas ON Users.id=chavrusas.luser_id  WHERE ((chavrusas.ruser_id)=id_txt and chavrusas.ended=false) AND (chavrusas.luser_type)<>(chavrusas.ruser_type) AND NOT ((chavrusas.luser_type)='teacher' AND (chavrusas.ruser_type)='student') AND NOT ((chavrusas.ruser_type)='teacher' AND (chavrusas.luser_type)='student'); UNION SELECT users.id, users.first, users.last, chavrusas.ruser_type AS user_type, chavrusas.id, users

Comment: You're getting your data in tabular format.  Your best bet for displaying it as shown in the query is a grid or a similar control depending on your requirements.  What might work is programmatically looping through the results of your query and building up a formatted string with what you want the user to see and then using this string with the MsgBox function.